# NSOpenGLView: NSWindow resizeIndicator is missing

Tags: cocoa, opengl, view, resize

I am currently creating a simple Cocoa Window programmatically with and NSOpenGLView attached to it. Anyways if I create the windows style mask with with `NSResizableWindowMask` and `[m_window setShowsResizeIndicator: YES ];` I'd expect to see the resize indicator in the bottom right. The resizing works, but the indicator does not show at all. I also checked simple NSOpenGLView examples and they also have the same problem so I am pretty certain that it's not a bug in my code but rather a problem with a view that has 100% width and height. Is there any way to position the indicator ontop of the NSOpenGLView?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NSOpenGLView will cover the resize indicator, no matter what you do. You can fake it positioning a custom texture at the bottom right corner of your View.

See this thread for detailed discussion and some example codes:

- http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-6160.html